# how can I make my const grow by 1 each time the command is ran AND make sure it's never the same number (unique id)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

so Im building a warning system, everything is ready and working now Im just working on a unique id for each warning. I got the logic behind it, all that's left it make it so the warning id grows by 1 each time and that it will never be the same Id as a different warning --> meaning that if a warning has the id 1 for example, there can never be another warning with the id 1 and the code will keep regenerating numbers until it reaches a number that doesnt exist on the database. I am using mongoDB to host my data base

here's the part in my code where Im trying to get it to work:

```
const warnID = 0
warnID+=1
const warning = {
  wId: warnID,
  author: message.member.user.tag,
  timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
  reason,
}
```

there's no error, I just need  help on how to do it. if possible to help me figure out how to do in on a different file and then export it to this one as I will need ids for my mute and unmute(both are on different files than the warns and each-other) database entries as well !!!

Comment: You can't add to a constant...

Answer (score 1):

`const` is short for "constant" and is immutable (meaning it should not change!).  If you need to change it, it should be declared as `let`.

Comment: thanks but how do I write it in the code then? like after I change it to let

Comment: Well I don't know the context of your code, and I don't think it helps to write it for you ;) if you want to increment your warnID value, you can declare it is `let warnId = 0` which will allow your `warnID+=1` to work.  If you are writing this to a database it is usually a better practice to allow the database to handle incrementing IDs like this. Storing it in memory will make warnID start at 1 after the program is restarted in this context.